# How to install Windows 7 using an external display?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, external-display, sony-vaio, windows-installation

I have a Sony Vaio VPCF115FM.

Through a lot of research online, I've come to find out that this laptop has external video ports (VGA & HDMI) that only work once the operating system loads the drivers for the nVidia graphics card. Therefore, you cannot see any of the boot process such as BIOS, POST, etc.

My problem is, the laptop display is cracked and I can't afford $200 for a screen (cheapest I can find) and I'm unemployed at the moment. Recently, my hard drive died, so I'm trying to reinstall the operating system (Windows 7). But since the nVIdia driver is not included in the install disk, I can't see antything on the screen.

Possible solutions  I could think of:

1. WindowsPE (e.g., Hiren's Boot Disk): I could use something like Hiren's because it contains a easy installer for Windows OS's. But again, no video graphics driver.

   How can I place a video driver in Hiren's, or even create a new PE with the driver included?
2. Figure out which keys I should press, in the correct order, to install the OS, reboot, and download and install the driver. (ugh)

What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

You could look in to `unattended install` mode for windows.